# Python: Return the name of a function within a function within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a decorator that measures execution time, and I'd like to print the function name along with the time. That's easy enough typically, as I can just use `function.__name__`. The tricky part is when I attach another decorator which is in the following format.

```
def retry_until(desired_return_value, retries=0):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
```

In this case I print `f.__name__` in the wrapper function and the value I get for `f.__name__` is wrapper(). I'd like the value to be the function name that is decorated. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

```
def get_execution_time(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        ret = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f.__name__ + "() completed in %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
        return ret
    return wrapper

@get_execution_time
def test():    # Function name is "test"
    pass

@get_execution_time
@retry_until(False, 2)
def test():    # Function name is "wrapper", the inner-most function in retry_until
    pass
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reassign `__name__` manually, or you could just use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to do that and a couple related things for you:

```
import functools
def retry_until(desired_return_value, retries=0):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for that. The wraps(f) decorator worked perfectly.